# getSelectionModel does not open while I use tabs

Tags: java, javafx

I am facing a problem that after I use .getSelectionModel in my function it doesn't open my selected tab. Tried to use .getTabs to check does it even work - worked. Here's my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Controller {

    public void loadinimas() {

    }
    /*---------------------- BENDROJO LANGO KINTAMIEJI ----------------------*/
    @FXML
    private Tab darbuotojuValdymas;
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    /*---------------------- PAGRINDINIO LANGO KINTAMIEJI ----------------------*/
    @FXML
    private Button pagrindinisInformacija;
    @FXML
    private Button pagrindinisDarbuotojuValdymas;

    /*---------------------- PAGRINDINIO LANGO METODAI ----------------------*/
    @FXML
    void pagrindinisInformacijaPateikti() {
        Alert a = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        a.setResizable(true); // Kad galima butu mazinti / didinti ALERTO langa
        a.setTitle("Informacija apie darbą");

        a.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    void pagrindinisDarbuotojuValdymasPateikti() {
       tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(darbuotojuValdymas);
    }
}
```

And here is my Scema view:
[image]

As a one member mentioned I forgot to upload my .FXML file.. My bad -_-. Here is my fxml file from Scema.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Pagrindinis">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="pagrindinisInformacija" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="59.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pagrindinisInformacijaPateikti" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="Informacija" />
                  <Button fx:id="pagrindinisDarbuotojuValdymas" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pagrindinisDarbuotojuValdymasPateikti" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="Darbuotojų valdymas" />
                  <Button layoutX="209.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="Komandų valdymas" />
                  <Button layoutX="209.0" layoutY="255.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="Užduočių valdymas" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab fx:id="darbuotojuValdymas" text="Darbuotojų valdymas">
         <content>
            <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Įtraukti naują darbuotoją">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Darbuotojų valdymas">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Darbuotojų sąrašas">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </content>
    </Tab>
      <Tab text="Komandų valdymas">
         <content>
            <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Naujos komandos sukūrimas">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Komandų valdymas">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Komandų sąrašas">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="Užduočių valdymas">
         <content>
            <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Naujos užduoties sukūrimas">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Užduočių valdymas">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Užduočių sąrašas">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Comment: Where do you call `pagrindinisDarbuotojuValdymasPateikti()`? The code you posted does not include the FXML; please provide a [mcve] for us to test.

Comment: I just updated my code from .FXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here, actually.

1. The `TabPane` you define in your `Controller` is different than the
   one in your `FXML` file because it does not have the `@FXML`
   annotation.
2. Your `FXML` does not provide an `fx:id` for your `TabPane` either.

To fix this, change your `Controller` to define the `tabPane` like this:

```
@FXML
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
```

And add the following attribute to the `<TabPane>` tag of your `FXML` file:

```
fx:id="tabPane"
```

**Problem Solved!**

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: As the `TabPane` is now being injected there's no need to initialize it; the value will just be overwritten.